# R paired column index

Tags: r

Say I have two matrix, A and B:

```
mth <- c(rep(1:5,2))
day <- c(rep(10,5),rep(11,5)) 
hr <- c(3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,7)  
v <- c(3,4,5,4,3,3,4,5,4,3)  
A <- data.frame(cbind(mth,day,hr,v))

year <- c(2008:2012)
mth <- c(1:5)  
B <- data.frame(cbind(year,mth))
```

What I want should be look like:

```
mth <- c(rep(2008:2012,2))  
day <- c(rep(10,5),rep(11,5))  
hr <- c(3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,7)  
v <- c(3,4,5,4,3,3,4,5,4,3)  
A <- data.frame(cbind(mth,day,hr,v))
```

Basically what I need is to change the column mth in A with column year in B, Maybe I didn't search for the right keyword, I was not able to get what I want(I tried which()), please help, thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but it is not at all clear what you want. What do you mean by `change` the mth column in`A` with `year` in `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A2 <- merge(A,B, by = "mth")[ , -1]
names(A2)[(which(names(A2)=="year"))] <- "mth"
> A2
   day hr v  mth
1   10  3 3 2008
2   11  3 3 2008
3   11  4 4 2009
4   10  4 4 2009
5   11  5 5 2010
6   10  5 5 2010
7   11  6 4 2011
8   10  6 4 2011
9   10  7 3 2012
10  11  7 3 2012
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest solution is to use `merge`, which is equivalent to a sql join in a lot of ways:

```
merge(A,B)
#-----
merge(A, B)
   mth day hr v year
1    1  10  3 3 2008
2    1  11  3 3 2008
3    2  11  4 4 2009
4    2  10  4 4 2009
5    3  11  5 5 2010
6    3  10  5 5 2010
7    4  11  6 4 2011
8    4  10  6 4 2011
9    5  10  7 3 2012
10   5  11  7 3 2012
```

You could also probably use `match` like this to replace mth in place:

```
A$mth <- B[match(A$mth, B$mth),1]
#-----
    mth day hr v
1  2008  10  3 3
2  2009  10  4 4
3  2010  10  5 5
4  2011  10  6 4
5  2012  10  7 3
6  2008  11  3 3
7  2009  11  4 4
8  2010  11  5 5
9  2011  11  6 4
10 2012  11  7 3
```

While a little dense, that code indexes `B` by matching the two `mth` columns from `A` and `B` and then grabs the first column.+